# How do I have TestNG run tests in specific groups (from the command-line)?

Tags: java, unit-testing, command-line, testng

I'm invoking TestNG from the command-line like this:

```
java org.testng.TestNG -groups "foo" testng.xml
```

...with the intention of only running tests annotated with:

```
@Test(groups = { "foo" })
```

...but it's running all my tests.  Do I need to change my testng.xml file?

```
<suite name="BarSuite" verbose="1">
  <test name="AllInPackage">
    <packages>
      <package name="com.example.bar"/>
   </packages>
 </test>
</suite>
```

Is TestNG ignoring the -groups command-line argument because testng.xml says to run all the tests in the package?  If so, how should I change my testng.xml file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You got it exactly right: if you specify a testng.xml, it takes precedence over the command line switches.

Just add the following to your XML file:

```
  <groups>
    <run>
      <include name="foo"  />
    </run>
  </groups>
```

Comment: That worked.  But don't I have to specify a testng.xml file?  Can I modify my testng.xml file so can use the -groups command-line option (instead of having a separate testng.xml file for each subset of groups I want to run)?

Comment: No answer to previous question? How to specify group from command line?

Comment: As I said in my answer, if you use -groups, you can't use a testng.xml. It's one or the other.

Answer (score 4):

**Java:**
Running tests with TestNG in specific groups is very easy:
1) Open you project folder in command line
example: `cd C:\FunctionalTests`
2) Run test by group

```
mvn test -Dgroups=group1,group2
```

group1, group2 - name of the test group
[example in java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWKfp.png)

NB!
`mvn test` command works, if your project building manager is [maven.](https://maven.apache.org/)
If you dont know, what kind of building manager you are using, you can verify it by checking (i.e) pom.xml existence in your project

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Thank you for feedback! Done.